# How to Perform proper SQL INSERT using MyBatis-SpringBoot-MySQL in XML-style?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, ibatis

Im having a hard time inserting a new data in my SQL database. Can someone check my mapper.xml and mapper.java?

*Actor.java* POJO

```
@Component
public class Actor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer actor_id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String last_update;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

*ActorMapper.xml*

```
 <insert id="insertNewActor" parameterClass="com.helios.mybatissakila.model.Actor" 
         useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="actor_id" keyProperty="actor_id">
     insert into actor (first_name,last_name,last_update) 
     values (#{first_name},#{last_name},#{last_update})
 </insert>
```

*Mapper.java* method

```
List <Actor> insertNewActor(Map<String, Object> actor);
```

*RESTController method*

```
@PostMapping(value="/actors", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public List<Actor> insertNewActor(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> actor) {
        return actorMapper.insertNewActor(actor);
    }
```

DB table structure:

[image]

Also, please notice if I should be using parameterClass or parameterType in mapper.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first remove the  @Component  Actor which is not needed.
then change mapper.java ,like this

```
int insertNewActor(Actor actor);
```

if it fails,show the error

Comment: thanks for the tip! Can you explain why @Component annotation is not needed?

Comment: Actor is just a pojo. it is used only by new and set some value. it not needed to put it into beanFactory .in my word. a @Component class usually is class which is depend on some class or is depended. a @Component class  usually as a `tool` .at last,forgive my poor english. you google it or read spring document